# How to create a Procedure in MYSQL with only a DELETE query?

Tags: mysql, parent-child, sql-delete

I am trying to create a MYSQL procedure that will delete a few records based on a few conditions but I keep on getting a `syntax error` when I have no `SELECT` statement in the procedure and only fill it with a `DELETE` query.

I am trying to delete records from a `child` table but I cant find any MYSQL procedure that **ONLY** delete records.

Does anyone have any examples that you would like to share? I have been stuck on this for a day now. Any help will be much appreciated

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_records()
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Sports
    WHERE   (Sports.idPerson= Person.idPerson) 
    AND     (Person.Country ='New Zealand')
    AND     (Sports.levelID= 1)
    AND     (Sports.difficulty = 5);    
    END
    //
    delimiter;
```

Comment: @MitchWheat there you go

Comment: like so? `DELETE FROM Sports USING Sports INNER JOIN Person` that doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform a DELETE with a join to another table, you need to use this syntax:

```
DELETE s FROM Sports s 
INNER JOIN Person p ON p.IdPerson = s.IdPerson
WHERE 
     p.Country = 'New Zealand'
     AND s.levelID = 1
     AND s.difficulty = 5;
```

Ref.: [DELETE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)